# REGEXP_SUBSTR to match URL subdirectory and group by results

Tags: regex, re2

Trying use REGEXP_SUBSTR to get the type/fruit extracted and group on this.

Data sample e.g

```
www.fruits.com/type/banana?=asdasdasdwa 
www.fruits.com/type/Apple?=asdasdasdwa
www.fruits.com/type/Apple?=asdasd21414
www.fruits.com/type/Orange?=asdasdasdwa
```

Using following SQL

```
  SELECT DATE
        COUNT(*) AS Sessions
       ,REGEXP_SUBSTR(hits.page.pagePath, '/type/?$',1, 1)
    FROM
      `159484249.ga_sessions_*`  WITH_VISIT
      LEFT JOIN UNNEST(hits) AS hits
      LEFT JOIN UNNEST(hits.customdimensions) AS customdimension
    WHERE
      _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) AND FORMAT_DATE("%Y%m%d", DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
      AND ((totals.pageviews>1 or totals.pageviews is null) or totals.totalTransactionRevenue is not null or totals.newVisits is null or totals.timeOnSite is not null)
      AND hits.page.pagePath LIKE '%/type/%' AND hits.type = 'PAGE'
     
    GROUP BY DATE,REGEXP_SUBSTR(hits.page.pagePath, '/type/?$',1, 1)
    
    ORDER BY DATE ASC, Sessions ASC;
```

Desired result

```
   Date       | Sessions | Type
   01/01/2021 | 22342    | type/apple
   02/01/2021 | 1000     | type/orange
   03/01/2021 | 2000     | type/banana
```

My query above returns null for Type

Comment: Please add more context here, what is the issue, what have you tried, etc.  If you're simply looking for the correct regex try something like this: `type\/\w+`

Comment: Yes trying to get the correct REGEXP_SUBSTR to return desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below you can see the usage of the regex string I provided in the comment to the question:

This would produce the correct substring you are looking for

```
with sample_data as (
  select 'www.fruits.com/type/banana?=asdasdasdwa' as url union all
  select 'www.fruits.com/type/Apple?=asdasdasdwa' union all
  select 'www.fruits.com/type/Apple?=asdasd21414' union all
  select 'www.fruits.com/type/Orange?=asdasdasdwa' union all
  select 'www.fruits.com/type/ban-a-na?=asdasdasdwa'

)

select regexp_substr(url, r'type\/\w+') original
  , regexp_substr(url, r'type\/([\w|-]+)?') dashses
from sample_data
```

This produces the following

[image]

Comment: Great thankyou, one last add if i may. What would be the regex for capturing dashes as well? e.g. type/ba-na-na and excluding the type\ so just the following apple | ba-nana etc.

Comment: updated to include the dash scenario.  If this was helpful please consider upvoting as well.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, is there somewhere that has all the rules/syntax etc

Comment: I will typically use this site: https://regex101.com/
It allows for testing, defining why a match occured,  and has common rules with descriptions